# Route more traffic through VPN

Tags: openvpn, route

I am using `openvpn` to connect to a VPN server, with the following configuration:

```
remote openvpn.vpn.domain.tld
port 1194
proto udp

dev tun
client
auth-user-pass login.conf
keepalive 10 60
```

After running `openvpn /etc/openvpn/client/myconf.conf`, the output of `ip route` is the following:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 src 192.168.1.25 metric 303 
129.31.0.0/16 via 129.31.250.1 dev tun0 
129.31.250.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 129.31.250.111 
146.169.0.0/16 via 129.31.250.1 dev tun0 
146.179.0.0/16 via 129.31.250.1 dev tun0 
155.198.0.0/16 via 129.31.250.1 dev tun0 
172.16.0.0/12 via 129.31.250.1 dev tun0 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.25 metric 303
```

This redirects some of the traffic through the VPN, which is usually enough for my purposes, but sometimes I would like to redirect *all* the internet traffic. I know that the option `redirect gateway def1` in the `openvpn` configuration does more or less that, but I would like a more flexible, manual solution. I thought that adding a default route via:

```
ip route add default via 129.31.250.1 dev tun0
```

would do that, but when I issue that command my browsers can't load websites anymore, so I suppose that something is wrong with it. Would anyone know where the problem might be coming from?

EDIT: Somehow, using `0.0.0.0/1` instead of `default` seems to have fixed the problem… If there is a reason why, I would still be interested in learning about it.

Comment: Would be nice if you answer your own question, and then set is as solution.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll look into possible causes of this behaviour and will post an answer if I find something interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "0.0.0.0/1" instead of "default" isn't fixing the problem.  At best, it's hiding it.

The problem is that if you set the default route into the tunnel (without having a more specific route to then VPN's endpoint), you are also changing the route that `openvpn` uses to connect to the remote endpoint of the VPN.  In other words, openvpn no longer knows how to get to the remote VPN endpoint.

You need to set a static route to your remote VPN provider (`openvpn.vpn.domain.tld`) to go via your original, non-VPN internet connection.

e.g., assuming that's on interface `wlp2s0`:

```
ip route add openvpn.vpn.domain.tld dev wlp2s0
```

BTW, you probably also need to set a route (or routes) for your ISP's network(s) and/or any essential services they provide you (e.g. DNS, mail service) to go via that connection too.  Your ISP probably only provides those services to IP addresses they own or know are downstream from them (i.e. not to some random IP address owned by some VPN provider on the other side of the world).

Comment: this is sometimes known (by crude people like me) as the tunnel disappearing up its own backside.